# How to transfer variables between voids

Tags: c#

I am getting this error:

> "The variable 'a' is assigned but its value is never available"

```
namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void test()
        {
            int a = 11;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should receive a *warning* of "The variable 'a' is assigned but its value is never used" and an *error* of "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context". It's not really clear what you're asking though, particularly as there aren't multiple classes here. You've got a local variable in the `test` method - if you want that variable's value at the end of the method, you should return it from the method.

Comment: Nitpick: you are not transferring "variables" but their "values"

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about "methods" not classes.
You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

But in the mean time, try this:

```
namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = test();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int test()
        {
            int a = 11;
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = test();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int test()
    {
        int a = 11;
        return a;
    }
}
```

You should probably get this error from your code. "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context"
As you do not get the variable "a" out from your method and try to access it.

Try the above and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a class and a method, what you have there. NOT 2 classes.
What do you want to do exactly?
The `a` variable does not exist where you want to print it.

Something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  test();
  Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void test()
{
  int a = 11;
  Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```